# how to protect Notify controller using same credentials as bot controller

Tags: botframework

In sample https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Controllers/NotifyController.cs can be used/accessed without authorization. 
How I can enable authorization using same credentials(appid,secret key) as my bot (BotController) configured ?
How to call it from client with this new credentials?
Thanks

Comment: What is your goal behind enabling authentication for NotifyController and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Protect notifyController from unauthorized access. And use same credentials as bot controller. I did not found any examples

Comment: I still don't get the point to secure the controller file. The notify controller is responsible for sending the proactive message to the bot. Each time the bot's notify page is requested, the notify controller retrieves the conversation references from the dictionary. You can't lock down a web page with the bot's appID and password.

Comment: Why not? You must to prevent anybody to start sending notifications to your customers. It is security hole. To don’t invent custom authorization I want to reuse same as bot use. In v3 was attribute  BotAuthentication . I can’t found details how to use it with v4.

Comment: User Authentication (what you want to keep someone from accessing your notify end point) is NOT the same as Bot Authentication (which is what the bot uses to verify messages to/from the bot's back end. There is no way to use the Bot's Authentication (nor should you want to) to verify users accessing your notification endpoint.

Comment: If you are still interested in looking for the equivalent of BotAuthentication(not available in v4) in v4, then refer to this comment on one of the Github issues.

Comment: @ranusharao can you please resend the link

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5268#issuecomment-458765493